# Running C++/WinRT quick-start but cause exception in VS2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-winrt

the Following is quick-start program of WinRT:

```cpp
// WinRT.cpp    
// Single source file runs

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp.lib")

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::Syndication;

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    Uri rssFeedUri{ L"https://blogs.windows.com/feed" };
    SyndicationClient syndicationClient;
    SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed = syndicationClient.RetrieveFeedAsync(rssFeedUri).get();
    for (const SyndicationItem syndicationItem : syndicationFeed.Items())
    {
        winrt::hstring titleAsHstring = syndicationItem.Title().Text();
        std::wcout << titleAsHstring.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've configured my compiler platform in Microsoft's tutorial, But Run failed and just throw an Exception:

[Platform: Release X64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5AfL.png)

[standard: ISO C++17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJ0V.png)

[Comfomance mode: No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJqU.png)

[Running but doesn't work !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVAvI.png)

[Exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5e3b.png)

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ojnF.png)

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD9C78A839 in WinRT.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error at memory location 0x000000F009CFFA00.

What went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error code [translates](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=-1073740791) to `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`. This exception is apparently repurposed to trigger a fail-fast path that immediately terminates the process without running any destructors. *Something* went catastrophically wrong. You can set up your debugger to break when this exception is raised, load up public symbols, and get closer to the root cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Founded solution. Ouput display **security channel supports errors**.

solution:
**Open TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2**